# Blackberry Listfield highlight color

Tags: blackberry, listfield

what is the best way to change the highlight (focus) color of a blackberry ListField, I have used the drawFocus method it does highlight thing but it's performance too slow to go on with

Code in drawlistrow

```
Item item = (Item)this.listData.elementAt(this.getSelectedIndex());

    g.drawText (item.getItemNumber(), 2, y, Graphics.LEFT,20);
    g.drawText (item.getDescription(), 25, y, Graphics.LEFT,30);
    g.drawText (item.getItemType(), 60, y, Graphics.LEFT,15);

    g.setColor(0xC4C3C4);
    g.drawLine(2, y, 2, 115);
```

Comment: add your drawlistrow code here

Comment: I have 5 different LISTS and want to add a generic code for focus highlighting I am only rendering data in drawlistrow method

Answer (score 1):

You can set the list field highlight colour using the following code

```
if (g.isDrawingStyleSet(Graphics.DRAWSTYLE_FOCUS)) {
    //change focus color
        g.setBackgroundColor(MyColors.LIGHT_GRAY);  
        g.clear();
    //draw text
        g.setFont(boldTextFont);
        g.setColor(MyColors.White);
        g.drawText(text, 12, y);
    }
```

Do add your drawlistrow code so we can help you improve the performance.

Comment: I need to change the default blue color of an item that appears on focus

Answer (score 0):

create one `boolean` for this screen. `boolean _inFocus = false;` . Than add two method (onfocus, onunfocus)in your `Listfield` constructor .`protected void onFocus(int direction) 
    {
         _inFocus = true;
        super.onFocus(direction);
    }
    protected void onUnfocus() 
    {
          _inFocus = false;
        super.onUnfocus();
    }` .

Than write down the below method in your `drawListRow` method . In the below method we will check that row is focusable or not.

```
if(_inFocus)
        {
            if(listField.getSelectedIndex() == index)
            {
                g.setGlobalAlpha(100);
                g.setColor(0xff9600);
                g.fillRect(0,y,getWidth(),getHeight());
                //invalidate();
            }
        }
```

This is the simple way to highlight row in `Listfield` . 
i hope it will help you.